# Ubuntu 20.4 stopped recognizing the audio driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, alsa

I have an integrated to the motherboard sound card, which was perfectly working with Ubuntu 20.4 until recent update or software installation (not fully sure which one and when it happened):

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"                                       21ms 
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 11
    Memory at df140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at df120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at df080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

I ended up with the `Dummy Output` and followed the official [Sound Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting). It appears that Ubuntu somehow lost its drivers:

```
System:    Host: ubuntu Kernel: 5.8.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: N/A 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP108 High Definition Audio driver: N/A
```

and

```
sudo aplay -l                                                        21ms 
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

Following Step 5 from the same guide I got:

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd                               5ms 
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-seq-device.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-ens1370.ko
```

Sadly, the next step from the guide fails despite updating all packages:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-restricted-modules-`uname -r` linux-generic                                           6ms 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-restricted-modules-5.8.0-40-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-restricted-modules-5.8.0-40-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-restricted-modules-5.8.0-40-generic'
```

The only potentially similar reported issue [Integrated sound card not working Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243254/integrated-sound-card-not-working-ubuntu-20-04) has no activity for 9 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163225/how-do-i-install-new-intel-hda-sound-driversp/). I was able to restore the drive with:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

Later I have followed the complete procedures suggested by Ubuntu guide:

```
sudo aplay -l
```

This followed by a reboot has fixed the problem.

**Edited 2021-02-23**

The problem reappeared after another automatic update and I had to reapply the same fix. It looks to me that the extra modules are not installed automatically and you need to add them manually.